# Does pure file uploading/downloading from Wolfram Cloud consume cloud credits?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

If I use `CopyFile` to copy a large file to the wolfram cloud (say `100MB`), and got say `10` downloads per day (for `1GB`/day of download activity), does this consume cloud credits (or cost extra money against most Wolfram/Mathematica subscriptions)?

Comment: Credits are not deducted for file operations like `CopyFile`, `FileExistsQ` and fetching cloud objects like `CloudGet` etc. For evaluating dynamic cloud objects like `APIFunction`/`FormFunction` and `CloudEvaluate` the user credits are deducted.

Comment: @dsingh That looks like an answer! Could you post it as such? It would also be nice if you could point us to a reference that supports that, or show us how you tested it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Credits are not deducted for file operations like `CopyFile`, `FileExistsQ` and fetching cloud objects like `CloudGet` etc.

```
In[137]:= $CloudCreditsAvailable

Out[137]= 5849525

In[138]:= CopyFile[$InstallationDirectory <> 
  "/Documentation/English/System/ExampleData/coneflower.jpg", 
 CloudObject[]]

Out[138]= \
CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/0fb031a3-ea72-413b-9b84-\
29667ef289f0"]

In[139]:= $CloudCreditsAvailable

Out[139]= 5849525
```

For evaluating dynamic cloud objects like `APIFunction`/`FormFunction`, running deployed `Manipulates` and `CloudEvaluate` the user credits are deducted.

e.g. Below evaluations will deduct credits.

```
CloudDeploy[Manipulate[a, {a, 1, 20}]] (* Using interactions in deployed objects. *)

In[129]:= api = 
 CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{"c" -> "Integer"}, #c! &], "factAPI"];

In[128]:= $CloudCreditsAvailable

Out[128]= 5849527

(* Evaluating APIFunction/FormFunction *)
In[130]:= URLExecute[api, {"c" -> 59}]

Out[130]= \
"138683118545689835737939019720389406345902876772687432540821294940160\
000000000000"

In[133]:= $CloudCreditsAvailable

Out[133]= 5849526

(* Using CloudEvaluate *)
In[134]:= CloudEvaluate[159!];

In[137]:= $CloudCreditsAvailable

Out[137]= 5849525
```

We are working on documenting cloud-specific functions extensively. I think its good to specify which functions will deduct credits. I will discuss with my team about it. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for posting it as an answer! Looking forward to more detailed documentation of cloud functions as well.